# Android Resource Packaging Error

Tags: android, mobile, apk

I'm getting an error on Android Studio when trying to generate a signed APK of my project. For some reason, I get an error "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/Icon3.png')." This doesn't make sense because my Icon3.png file is pasted in my @drawable folder, as you can see in
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fpCw.png). The error is due to line 12, where my cursor is.

Why doesn't it recognize it when that's exactly where the file is?

Comment: your image name is icon and you have written icon.png ? try taking .png put..

Comment: I already tried that. It still didn't work.